# Changing innerHTML breaks parentNode when anchor tag is overwritten? How to fix?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two event handlers set for the click event. One on all the `<th>`s in a table, and another generic one on the document.

Part of the code in the `<th>` handler changes the innerHTML of the clicked element. Crucially, I think, there's an anchor tag inside the `th` tag.

Part of the code in the document handler checks the parentNode of the clicked element.

It *appears* that these two facts cause a problem. If I comment out the innerHTML modification line, everything works fine. If I leave it in though, I get "null" for the element's `parentNode`.

Is this a known problem, and if so what's the solution? Is it a bug in Chrome, or is this how JavaScript/the DOM behave for some reason?

```js
function isInside(eChild, eParent) {
  alert('element is ' + eChild);
  if (eChild === eParent) {
    return true;
  }

  if (eChild === document) {
    return false;
  }

  return isInside(eChild.parentNode, eParent);
}

function init1() {
  document.getElementById('th').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('th').innerHTML = '<a href="#">Changed</a>';
  });
}

function init2() {
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (isInside(e.target, document.getElementById('table'))) {
      alert('found in table');
    } else {
      alert('not found in table');
    }
  });
}

init1();
init2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="th"><a href="#">Click me</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

If you comment out the

```
document.getElementById('th').innerHTML = '<a href="#">Changed</a>';
```

line in the JavaScript you'll experience the desired behaviour.

I assume it's because the event is firing on the `<a>` rather than on the `<th>`, and I'm then replacing that anchor with a new one in the innerHTML call. How would I fix that?

Comment: can you share the relevant code snippet?

Comment: Without a snippet, its unclear as to which parts of the DOM is being affected

Comment: No it's not a problem, and is likely something else in your code. Please provide the relevant code that shows this issue, otherwise this question is off-topic.

Comment: Generally speaking, the answer is "no". It works fine [here](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/VeWbqY), for example. `th` handler changes the `th`'s `innerHTML`, `document` handler wants the `th`'s `parentNode`, and gets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the element that was clicked no longer exists in the document at the point that its parentNode is requested. You've replaced it with an entirely different element.

Instead of changing the innerHTML of the parent, therefore replacing the element that was clicked with a new element, simply alter the existing element.

I've condensed the full demo below to save space, however the meat of the solution is here:

```
var th = document.getElementById('th');
var link = th.querySelector('a');

th.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  link.textContent = 'Changed';
});
```

Here's the demo:

```js
function isInside(eChild, eParent) {
  alert('element is ' + eChild);
  if (eChild === eParent)  return true;
  if (eChild === document) return false;
  return isInside(eChild.parentNode, eParent);
}

var th = document.getElementById('th');
var link = th.querySelector('a');

th.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  link.textContent = 'Changed';
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (isInside(e.target, document.getElementById('table'))) alert('found in table');
  else alert('not found in table');
});
```

```html
<table id="table"><thead><tr><th id="th"><a href="#">Click me</a></th></tr></thead></table>
```